# How to autorotate from portrait to landscape mode?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can I autorotate an image from portrait to landscape mode on the IPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display a new and different view, the simplest and cleanest solution is to push a new view controller (presentModalViewController) that only supports landscape mode (in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:).

Comment: – shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: Deprecated in iOS 6.0. See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:).

Answer (score 4):

You have to implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method in your controller, like this

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Apply proper transformation to the view and adjust its frame bounds

In my app I've done it this way (very likely not the best one):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5f];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 480.0f, 320.0f);

self.view.center = CGPointMake(160.0f, 240.0f);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: NB: this used to be correct, but is no longer needed (Apple changed the way the API works so that this stuff happens automagically)