# How to rotate screen to landscape?

Tags: iphone

How to rotate screen to landscape ?

Can you suggest simple code ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402/iphone-app-in-landscape-mode or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437636/how-to-autorotate-from-portrait-to-landscape-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trickier than you first think! After much discussion this blog post (with a link to further discussion afterwards) contains the cleanest answer:

[How to Switch to Landscape Mode at will](http://simonwoodside.com/weblog/2009/2/27/iphone_programming_how_to_switch/)

Answer (score 2):

in the uiViewController you should have the method

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
 return YES;
}
```

in order to rotate automatically.

If your app has an uiTabBarController then you have to subclass the UITabBarController and add the method to it also.Something like this:

```
@interface MyTabBarController : UITabBarController {

}

@end

#import "MyTabBarController.h"

@implementation MyTabBarController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: – shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: Deprecated in iOS 6.0. See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:).

Answer (score 0):

This howto describes how you can enable auto rotation in your application:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/UserExperience/index.html#GENERAL-HANDLE_AUTOROTATION_OF_MY_USER_INTERFACE

This howto describes how you can start your application in landscape mode:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/UserExperience/index.html#GENERAL-START_MY_APPLICATION_IN_LANDSCAPE_MODE

Answer (score 0):

Thanks SorinA. Needing `UITabBarController` `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` gave me all sorts of frustrations since it is not a class that I was subclassing for any reason (i.e., the default functionality was fine for my app).

As a lighter-weight solution than subclassing I used a category (maybe its all the same, but it seems lighter weight).

```
@interface UITabBarController (WithRotation)
@end

@implementation UITabBarController (WithRotation)
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
@end
```

p.s. If you only want to support some orientations, test the interfaceOrientation and only return YES in the appropriate orientations.

p.p.s. What is the info.plist `Supported interface orientations` for? The only thing that seems to matter is what is returned from `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`

Comment: – shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: Deprecated in iOS 6.0. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:).

Answer (score 0):

Just implement this in your view controller file, 
and you're done.

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation
{
     return YES;
}
```

Comment: – shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: Deprecated in iOS 6.0. See [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:).