# Lock child UIViewController to Portrait only in iOS 8

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I have a Navigation Controller that contains a Parent UIViewController that supports all orientation. I want my Parent UIViewController to present its Child UIViewController that only supports Portrait orientation only. How can this be done in iOS 8?

I tried settings the supportedInterfaceOrientations to return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait only for my Child UIViewController, but it's not working.

Comment: I belive it bcoz there are some change in iOS 8. I found the answer in this post, check it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357162/how-to-force-view-controller-orientation-in-ios-8

Comment: For more clear explanation, I found his blog following by best practice both Single UIViewController and ViewContoller that embedded with UINavigationConroller and UITabBarController. http://koreyhinton.com/blog/lock-screen-rotation-in-ios8.html

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do that is:

In your child View Controller you can define this delegate method:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

add this line at the begin of your ViewDidLoad method:

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

This is a simple solution to force orientation in Portrait mode.

Comment: May not be the most elegant solution but works great for me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to update provided it seems that there is a proper answer at 
[Support landscape for only one view in UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023487/support-landscape-for-only-one-view-in-uinavigationcontroller)

Comment: I tried that on the Parent, but the supportedInterfaceOrientations  method is not called for the Child's. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with presenting? Presenting modally on top of parent or just pushing into navigation stack?

Comment: Sry I meant pushing. In my Parient UIViewController, I have a method that pushes my Child UIViewController on my navigationController. I used [self.navigationController pushViewController: childController animated:YES]; for pushing my child UIViewController.